# non-breaking, normal-sized space after period

Tags: spacing, punctuation

I know that a backslash will produce a normal-sized space after a period `i.e.\ like this`
and I know that a tilde will produce a non-breaking space, as in `Figure~1`.

What if I want a non-breaking space after an abbreviating period in the middle of a sentence, like when `referring to Eq.\~1`?

Until now I have just been using `~` in such circumstances but I've noticed that occasionally there is an inter-sentence space in between Eq. and 1.

Comment: Can you provide an example of such an inter-sentence space? `~` should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This demonstrates that the issue is not that the period looks like an end of sentence, but that `~`, while non-breaking, is *stretchable*.  If you don't want it to stretch, you can place it in an `\mbox`, or instead use a `\kern`.  Of course, removing the stretch from `~` will only make it harder to justify the remainder of the line.

In the first example, the `~` is slightly compressed.  In the 2nd, it is quite expanded.  In the 3rd, I use a `\kern` to prevent stretch, and in the 4th, I use an `\mbox` to prevent stretch.

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth1in
\begin{document}
xxxxxx Fig.~1 xxxxxxx

\sloppy

xxxx Fig.~1 xxxxxxx

xxxx Fig.\kern.75ex1 xxxxxxx

xxxx \mbox{Fig.~1} xxxxxxx
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to redefine `~` to a different stretch, for example `\renewcommand~{\nobreak\hspace{.75ex minus .5ex}}`.  In that case, the above MWE with that change becomes

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

To answer the OP's comment about whether the sequence `.~` can produce end-of-sentence spacing, or merely a stretchable space, this MWE demonstrates that it is the latter.  Note that `\@` overcomes the end-of-sentence nature of a `.`

We see that `.~` behaves the same as `.\@~` rather than `.` followed by a space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
x. z

x.~z

x.\@~z
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ok thanks. Just to be clear then, `.~` should produce a period and a stretchable space, but not the extra space that happens in between sentences?

If so then the extra space I saw in `Eq.~1` may just be due to the line justification, and because the period is a small glyph with lots of room above it!

Comment: @jms547  I believe that is the case.  You can always use `\@` to overrule the end-of-line period space.  So compare `x. z

x.~z

x.\@~z` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, `~` is a shorthand for `\nobreakspace{}` and `\nobreakspace` is defined as

```latex
% latex.ltx, line 1614:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\nobreakspace}{%
   \leavevmode\nobreak\ }
```

In turn, `\nobreak` is the same as `\penalty10000`; `\leavevmode` is used to ensure that the penalty is issued in horizontal mode, so as to inhibit any line break at the spot. The glue (space) inserted by `\␣` (backslash space) cannot be used as a line break point, because it is preceded by a penalty, which is a discardable item.

The TeXbook, on page 285, specifies

> - `\␣`. A control-space command appends glue to the current list, using the same amount that a ⟨space token⟩ inserts when the space factor is 1000.

So no extra space is inserted, independently from the space factor code of the preceding character.

Therefore `Eq.\ 1` and `Eq.~1` are equivalent as far as the amount of inserted space is concerned; the latter disallows a line break between `Eq.` and `1`.

However, the interword glue is usually flexible (stretchable and shrinkable) and will adjust for justification by the same factor as all other spaces in the same line.